# Como puedo pasar este query de SQL a LINQ usando EF Core

Tags: c#, linq

Es para un gráfico quiero el monto total de las facturas mensual y de tener alguna devolución también
el monto total, quiero hacerlo si es posible con solo linq.

**Este es el query de SQL**

```
select format(Factura.FechaDocumento,'MM.yyyy') as TotalFacturado,
sum(Factura.Monto), sum(Devolucion.Monto) as TotalDevoluciones 
from VenFactura
left join Devolucion on Devolucion.FacturaId = Factura.Id
where Factura.FechaDocumento >= '2019-09-01'
GROUP BY format(Factura.FechaDocumento,'MM.yyyy')
```

**Esto es lo que llevo de LINQ (pero no lo he logrado con las devoluciones)**

```
using (var db = new context())
{
     return db.Factura
            .Where(f => f.FechaDocumento >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
            .GroupBy(f => new { f.FechaDocumento.Month, f.FechaDocumento.Year})
            .Select(f => new dto
            {
                Mes = f.Key.Month,
                TotalFacturado = f.Sum(t => t.Monto)
            )
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();
};
```

Comment: Pueden obviar los <br> soy nuevo y no quería hacer el salto de línea.

Comment: te estaria faltando el join

Comment: Trate pero con el .Include() de EF Core, voy a ver si me resuelve el join